# How to match for an Option with multiple fields?

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

How do I match for an Option with multiple fields? I have the following code:

```
let opt_windowrecv = glfw_context.create_window(1280, 720, "Hello World!", glfw::Windowed); // returns Option<(Window, Receiver<(f64, WindowEvent)>)>

let window = match opt_windowrecv { // Does not compile
    Some(window, _) => window,
    None            => return
};
```

It complains saying:

> this pattern has 2 fields, but the corresponding variant has 1 field

Using this workaround does however work:

```
let opt_windowrecv = glfw_context.create_window(1280, 720, "Hello World!", glfw::Windowed); // returns Option<(Window, Receiver<(f64, WindowEvent)>)>

let windowrecv = match opt_windowrecv {
    Some(windowrecv) => windowrecv,
    None            => return
};

let (window, _) = windowrecv;
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the Rust compiler? I am using the [glfw-rs library](https://github.com/bjz/glfw-rs/).

Comment: It's not an option with multiple fields, it's an option with single *tuple* field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let window = match opt_windowrecv {
    Some((window, _)) => window,
    None            => return
};
```

Should work. The destructuring of `Some` should be a tuple, not 2 arguments.